# How to create bootstrap dropdown without jquery

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i want to create bootstrap dropdown without using jquery

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

please help how to do this

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dropdown can help you?

Comment: will you please provide some more details?

Answer (score 0):

Rememebr  adding ui-bootstrap directive to angular.module

Html Code

```
    <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Js Code

```
   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DropdownCtrl', function   ($scope, $log) {
   $scope.items = [
       'The first choice!',
       'And another choice for you.',
       'but wait! A third!'
     ];

    $scope.status = {
      isopen: false
                    };

      $scope.toggled = function(open) {
         $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
      };

    $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
    };

    $scope.appendToEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#dropdown-long- content'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my Dropdown menu script No Jquery No Bootstrap js, only bootstrap css which is easy to override anyway:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// -----Dropdown----------

// Rule: link.dropdown-link data-dropdown='dropdownIdentifier' div#dropdownIdentifier
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-link');
for (dropdown of dropdowns) {
    dropdown.onclick = function (e) {
        let dropdownDiv = document.getElementById(dropdown.getAttribute('data-dropdown'))
        if (dropdownDiv.style.display == "block") {
            dropdownDiv.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdownDiv.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
});
```

Now in html:

```
<a class="dropdown-link" data-dropdown="dropdownId">Prodbox</a>
<div id="dropdownId" class="dropdown-menu">
1
2
3
</div>
```

Note that dropdown-menu is bootstrap class to style it, you can write your own if you are not using bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 5 bundled via webpack you can do it by creation of new Dropdown instance.

Example:

```js
import Dropdown from 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
 
const dropdownEl = document.getElementById('dropdown');
new Dropdown(dropdownEl /*, options*/);
```

Details about options [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#options).